# Hide everything before my app starts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, kiosk

For a kiosk computer (no keyboard, no mouse, only touch screen), I would like to hide everything before my app starts, or replace it by a custom logo. How can I do this?

1. **Disable the display of BIOS message:** is this possible? (let's say it's a standard desktop computer with an Intel i5 and a medium-range ASUS motherboard)

   [image]
2. **Disable Debian 8 or Ubuntu loading screen:** how to do this?

   [image]
3. **Disable Desktop Environment loading screen:** is it possible?
4. Run my app (which has a GUI)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this would be hardware (or rather firmware) dependant, and I don't know of any that can do this out of the box.

One method that comes to mind is an IP controlled power or video switch that you could trigger at the start of your application.

Another method would be to do the same using the serial interface found on some industrial displays.

Comment: Let's say it's an average desktop computer (Intel i5, ASUS motherboard, and an average 17" flat monitor or a touch screen).

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible. You should consider the IP controlled power or video switch.

Comment: Ok, at least, how would you handle 2. and 3. ?

Comment: You would not trigger the power/display switch until your app started.

Comment: Let's say I don't have such a switch, what would you recommend on Linux config to have a custom loading screen?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Linux internals for this. One more thing you can look into is using a second display. It's probably easier to programmatically enable/disable that than to modify what's on the main display. You could probably do this without having a monitor connected to the primary.